# Login Registration with Two different account types

Tags: php, forms, authentication, registration, accounts

I am making a website login and registration page and it is working perfectly. Now I am in the part were I need to have two account types. Like Homeowner Account and Rentors Account.

Now what I have so far is I register and pick Homeowner Account It will go to a profile page with links and Images and that is relevant to that Account.

Register/Login-->Homeowner Account--->Homeowner Profile Page

But now When I register as a Rentors Account it goes to the same page with all the Homeowner Links. So How can I have it where I can read login and have the database read and determine which account type it has and then redirect it to the proper profile page (i.e. rentor profile).

Register/Login-->Rentor Account--->Rentors Profile Page

Also the reason why I want to have it direct to a different profile page is bc the visual looks of both Homeowner and Rentors Page is different with differnt colours and images.

I am working in php and mysql and have a database call users that has all the users info including the account type.

Thanks

Comment: add role at the registration stage.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field in that table and assign two role like homeowner and rentors. Then at the registration time insert this field with some value (homeowner and rentors) or (1 and 2). Then check at the time of login then redirect to corresponding profile.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column in your table that will hold the type of account a user holds.
At registration, include an input field where the account type is set.
Your login script should be able to determine the account type associated with the username/password combo that was typed in.
Using the account type that was returned from the table, the user can be redirected to the appropriate page. Something like: if($user_type == "Homeowner") { header("Location: homeoweners_page.php);} else { header("Location: rentors_page.php");}